# Image is not centering on page

Tags: html, css

For some reason, my image that I load though my post does not load centered. It loads at the top left of the page like there is no css on the page whatsover. I have gone over the code several of times but I can not figure out what is wrong with it.

The following code is my index.php

```
<?php $i = urlencode($_GET['i']); 

$image = str_replace("%2F", "/", $i);


?>
<head>
<title>RizzelDazz Images</title>

<Style type=css>
*
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#over
{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    text-align: center; /*handles the horizontal centering*/
}
/*handles the vertical centering*/
.Centerer
{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.Centered
{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="over">
    <span class="Centerer">
   <?php if($i=="") { echo ""; } else { echo"<img src='/../images" . $image . ".jpg'/>"; } ?>
   </span>
</div>


</body>
```

Comment: Instead of `.Centerer {...}` try `span .Centerer {...}`

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/K7y8f/

Comment: @Fred-ii- That did not seem to work

Comment: You can try `<style type="text/css">`

Comment: @APAD1 That is what I don't udnerstand. It works there.

Comment: Paste up the HTML code that is generated by the PHP file, it's hard to tell what's going wrong based on the raw PHP code.

Comment: @AndersG That sort of worked, now its centered at the top middle

Comment: Your `#over` id only shows `position:absolute;` but you haven't given any `x-y` positions. That could be a factor. Plus what Anders G mentioned. `<Style type=css>` is invalid syntax. You can do `<style>` also or `<style type="text/css">`

Comment: @user3546563 That's probably because now it's interpreted as style by the browser. Now you may see **[this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7310398/2311559)** for centering the image vertically. Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

If the code you posted is the entire content of your `index.php` file, you have several issues:

1. You have no `doctype`.  Include `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of your `index.php` file.
2. You have no `<html></html>` tags.  Everything in your document should be go inside `<html></html>` tags.
3. Your opening `<style>` tag is wrong. You have it as `<Style type=css>`; it should be:

   `<style type="text/css">` (no capital letters, quotes around `text/css`)

Here is your code with these changes - they will most likely fix your issues.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php $i = urlencode($_GET['i']);
    $image = str_replace("%2F", "/", $i);
?>
<head>
<title>RizzelDazz Images</title>
<style type="text/css">
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#over {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    text-align: center; /*handles the horizontal centering*/
}
/*handles the vertical centering*/
.Centerer {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.Centered {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="over">
    <span class="Centerer">
    <?php if($i=="") { echo ""; } else { echo"<img src='/../images" . $image . ".jpg'/>"; } ?>
    </span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you need to add

```
<style type="text/css">
```

rather than just

```
<style type="css">
```

It will still work on jsfiddle as there is no need to state a style type.  Hope this helps :)